# Does angular ng build also take care of library dependencies?

Tags: angular

I want to build an Angular project and have it deployed on a Tomcat server.

My doubt is that if I build the project with ng build will simply adding the files inside the dist directory be enough to deploy the project?

My main concern is if I have added any third party libraries, will they also be resolved in the final build?

Also, can the same result be achieved using AoT Compilation?

Comment: Assuming you are building with `ng-cli`, anything in the `dependencies` configuration of your project's `package.json` will be bundled into the `vendor.js` file generated during the build.

Comment: What are you using to build your app? Angular CLI? Custom Webpack?

Comment: I am using Angular CLI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not need anything but the contents of the "dist" for deployment.

Any third party dependencies that you install using the NPM (Node package Manager) will be included in the build. Any dependencies being imported on your index.html file, will not be bundled in your build. I would make sure my index.html has no third-party references that are available also as NPM packages. If they're not available then you would have to manually make these dependencies available in your production environment.

Ng build uses AOT, this is what prevents the build if any errors are found, and gives you the detailed error description.

As a side note, "ng build" will use hashing every time you build to give each build file a unique file name (e.g. "main.a16297a1c00ff481ec60.js"). This helps your users by preventing their browser from caching files that will later conflict with other builds and updates you may deploy, as the browser wont pull updated files if it already has the same filename on its cache memory. If you wanted to disable the hashing to have consistent names that you can directly reference, use this flag to build: ("ng build --prod --output-hashing none").

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank You!